# Css file not loading after static content flush in Magento 2.1.8

Tags: less-css, magento-2.1.8

I have a custom CSS file created and loaded through code. The **compile less** option is set to **yes** in configuration settings. When I clear the **static content flush** from cache management in admin panel and reload frontend, it gives an error that the CSS file not found `pub/static/frontend/vendor/modulename/en_US/css/test.css`. But when I run command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` my **test.css** file is loaded. I have my apache run through user **test** and Magento ownership is also **test**. 
How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check you magento site mode is **development** then

**File Path : pub/static/.htaccess**

```
  RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
```

This code is automatically copied the files

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clear **pub/static folder** exept *.htaccess* ?
Then **setup:static-content:deploy**